# Why not 1.Nf3 d5 2.c4 Nf6 against the Reti opening?

Tags: opening

The reply 2...Nf6 to the Reti opening 1.Nf3 d5 2.c4 Nf6 is not even mentioned in my three Reti opening books. What is wrong with that? There must be a well-known answer that is simply part of the professional player's erudition because otherwise this move would get attention from the authors.

[image: rnbqkb1r/ppp1pppp/5n2/3p4/2P5/5N2/PP1PPPPP/RNBQKB1R w KQkq - 1 3]]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is identical to the position that occurs after the move order `1. Nf3 Nf6 2. c4 d5`. The central push `d5` is common in many openings, for instance the Grunfeld, but here the timing is bad. The position after

```
[FEN ""]
[Title "Reti 2... Nf6"]
[Startply "7"]

1. Nf3 d5 2. c4 Nf6 3. cxd5 Nxd5 4. d4
```

is one I often get with white when I play online, and it usually ends up very well for white. White will follow up with `e4` and get an advantage in the center with tempo.

The main difference with the Grunfeld is that there is no white knight on `c3` that black can exchange the knight on `d5` with, and the knight (and black's whole position) will end up slightly passive.

Sample line:

```
[FEN ""]
[Title "Reti 2... Nf6"]
[Startply "13"]

1. Nf3 d5 2. c4 Nf6 3. cxd5 Nxd5 4. d4 g6 5. e4 Nb6 6. h3 Bg7 7.Nc3
```

with a slight white advantage.

Black can also try `4... Bf5` to stop `e4` temporarily, but then they have to be really careful. For instance

```
[FEN ""]
[Title "Reti 2... Nf6"]
[Startply "15"]

1. Nf3 d5 2. c4 Nf6 3. cxd5 Nxd5 4. d4 Bf5 5. Qb3 e6 6. Nc3 Nc6 7.e4 Nxc3 8. exf5!
```

is very good for white.

Comment: I have already accepted this answer but upon reflection I find that it still needs to be shown that White has an evident advantage after 1.Nf3 d5 2.c4 Nf6 3.cxd5 Nxd5 4.d4 c5, which hopes for a Gruenfeld or Alekhine like position.

Comment: After `4... c5`, `5. Nc3` transposes to a line from the Symmetrical English, but I believe `5. e4` is even stronger.

Answer (score 0):

White gets a strong center after chasing the Knight.

```
[fen ""]
1. Nf3 d5 2. c4 Nf6 3. cxd5 Nxd5 4. d4 e6 5. e4
```

This is a simplistic answer, there is more theory about the placement of pieces which is why 4. ... Bf5 is considered a bad move.

Answer (score 0):

The position after `1. Nf3 d5 2. c4 Nf6 3. cd5 Nxd5 4. Nc3` is column 62 of MCO-15 in the English Opening. I would look under the English for more on this line.

Comment: This is true, but `4. d4` is a bigger problem for black.